# How to display (x,y) coordinates in a listplot graph

Tags: plotting

I need to plot a listplot with its $(x,y)$ coordinate when my mouse go over a value of the function.

I want the **simplest** way to do it.

I have read topic using the notations "#", I just learnt how it works but if you use it I would like to have some explanations (that also could be an example for me to understand well how it works).

Comment: Try right-clicking the plot and use "Get Coordinates? tool

Comment: The problem is it is referenced to the origin of the picture. When i resize it it doesn't correspond. What's more it returns values where my mouse is and i just want a value on the function to have the exact result

Answer (score 4):

### Data

Fake data, you use your own.

```
data = Transpose[{Range[10], RandomReal[1, 10]}];
```

### Simple solution

Auxiliary function to add [`Tooltip`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tooltip.html)

```
addXYToolTip[{x_, y_}] := Tooltip[{x, y}, {x, y}]
```

The [`ListPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListPlot.html)

```
ListPlot[
 Map[addXYToolTip, data]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

### Better solution

```
data2 = Transpose[Sort /@ RandomReal[1, {2, 20}]]
addXYToolTip2[{x_, y_}, {n_}] := Tooltip[
  {x, y}
  , Framed@Grid[
    {
     {"n: ", n},
     {"x: ", x},
     {"y: ", y}
     },
    Alignment -> Left]
  ]

ListPlot[
 MapIndexed[addXYToolTip2, data2]
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

In:

```
xss = Table[{x, Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi, 0.05}];
mouseover[c_] := Mouseover[c, Text[c, c + {-0.2, 0.2}]]
plot[xss_] := xss // Map[mouseover] // ListPlot
plot[xss]
```

Out:
[image]

Comment: interesting!!!!

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) + [`Dynamic`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dynamic) as follows:

```
(* sample data *)
data=Table[{x,Sin[x]},{x,0,Pi,.1}];

(* nearest function *)
nf=Nearest[data];

ListPlot[
    data,
    Epilog -> Dynamic @ DynamicModule[
        {
            pt=nf[MousePosition[{"Graphics",Graphics},{0,0}]],
            scaled=MousePosition[{"GraphicsScaled",Graphics},None]
        },

        If[scaled===None,
            {},
            {
                Text[pt[[1]], pt[[1]], {1.5 Sign[scaled[[1]]-.5], 0}, Background->White],
                AbsolutePointSize[7], Point[pt], White, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[pt]
            }
        ]
    ]
]
```

[image]

As long as the mouse pointer is in the graphic, the nearest data point will get highlighted.